# Visualization of large 2d-grid data with very large height value

Tags: c++, opencv, data-structures, visualization

I have a large scientific data in z = f(i,j), where i and j are integers and z can be usually between e.g. 0 to 1e20, and it cannot all fit in memory.  I'd like to visualize this using a heat map (using log scale). The question is if there's a framework that can manage the data structure and also visualize, like OpenCV (but I don't think it can handle arbitrarily large z values; I know very little about OpenCV).

If I were to implement it, I'd represent the z height values into tiles, and then make smaller versions by averaging them to make even smaller tiles.  This can then be used to pan and zoom interactively.  And there's some compression that might be needed to reduce disk usage.

Any good libraries to do this? C++ preferred and GPL would not work for me. Thanks in advance.  I just noticed STXXL and HDF5 for data structures.  Would these help?

Comment: OpenCV is not a visualization library! Have a look at openGL and "MegaTexture"

Comment: I somehow thought OpenCV has hooks to render.  MegaTexture seems related, except I need to work with data that has much higher range (billions of trillions) and not raster images (0 to 255). Thanks.

Comment: "z can be usually between e.g. 0 to 1e20, and it cannot all fit in memory" - why large **values** can't fit in memory ?

Comment: HOW do you want to render? You must scale your "data values" to fit the "color values" range anyways... openCV is a library to extract information from images (computer vision) and have some minor visualization functions.

Comment: re: borisbn. a single z value will obvious fit in memory. many z values (with i and j ranging to billions), all these height values will not fit in memory.

Comment: re: Micka
I need to represent the data and also render.  The rendering will eventually get mapped to a color, but I need to preserve the original height values. E.g. we can change the colormap from log scale to linear.

Comment: The question is, whether you can do the mapping during reading => only hold your render-image in 24 bit BGR (while providing original precision for computation)?!?

Comment: Btw I guess you will have to implement it yourself. MegaTextures (virtual texturing) and rendering with openGL is more about a hint of HOW to do it.